# How to track what parameters are modified according to Facebook Publisher in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom-3, facebook

Lightroom tells me in the Facebook publisher that a certain set of photos needs to be re-published as they are modified. I didn't modify the photos directly and would like to know what has been changed that these photos need to be re-published.

Is there a way to find or track the modified parameters (keywords, develop settings, etc...)?

Comment: I'd think that what it's looking at is the last-modified time stamp on the XMP files, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and it is still present in LR4. LR-Facebook publish thinks that it has been changed even if it hasn't or only in irrelevant ways for Facebook.

Particularly, this happens to me if you re-authenticate into Facebook, or if you make a change to your FB-publish settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before.  Sometimes it isn't what you've done but what Facebook has done on their end.  If they've changed something, Lightroom "sees" and inconsistency and flags it for "re-publish".

Have you also look at the image history for changes?

Have you renamed a keyword in the global metadata list?  Have you moved the photos to another folder on your system?  These things have caused a "re-publish" in the past.