# Adobe Lightroom marks photos as modified without any user interaction

Tags: lightroom, adobe, lightroom-6

I make use of Adobe Lightroom's "Publish Services" in order to get my photos where I want them. I use the following publish services: Facebook, Flickr (also jf Flickr in the past), SmugMug and jf Collection Publisher. In all cases, photos mysteriously get marked as "Modified Photos to Re-Publish" without me touching lightroom at all.

For example, last night I published 169 photographs. Today, having not used Lightroom at all since last night's publish, 44 of those photographs are in the "Modified Photos to Re-Publish" tab. It is extremely annoying. I am aware that I can "Mark as Up-To-Date", but that isn't a solution to the real problem.

I see that a [similar question was asked 3 years ago](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39966/how-to-track-what-parameters-are-modified-according-to-facebook-publisher-in-lig), and I suspect there is no update to this problem. I am currently using Lightroom CC 2015.6.1 (build 1083169).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible causes of this.

One can be changes to metadata, not images (and you have some control over this in each publishing setup).  These changes can in fact be indirect, for example changes to a keyword itself can cause republishing of every photo with that keyword attached.  Some plugins (Smugmug's own for example) will be smart about the republish and send only the metadata, though you cannot see this in the published folder display itself.

There was also a bug/feature in 2015.6 (I think -- the one where they introduced the adjustable upright features).  This resulted in a different set of develop data internally when it was used, giving a different digest and in turn marking it for publish.  The bug/feature was that if you did NOT have a preview built for an image before the upgrade, building the preview would change the develop data, which in turn would mark the image to republish.  You could quite literally sit on a published folder, and as it would build previews watch one by one images flip from published to to-publish.  Supposedly this was addressed in the next version, though also adobe never really acknowledged what I saw (their comments were all Mac related but I saw this on Windows).  I did a build of standard previews of all images, then marked all as published (as they were when I started), but this was VERY tedious as you have to do it by published collection.

The other possibility is that the publishing is not being successful, though you can probably see this.  Some of the online publish plugins can get errors, leaving the image still marked for publish on the next run (as opposed to retrying in that publish run).

And of course changing image data, as you would expect, can cause it.

Comment: Building previews marking them as updated is a good theory. I'll look into that. However, I do have the latest version of Lightroom, and if that bug was indeed fixed, then I'm guessing it is something else.

Comment: Nope... no amount of mucking around with previews seemed to mark a published photo as needing update. I tried deleting previews, rebuilding them, several times, and it stayed in the published section as it should.

Comment: My comment on previews was related to a version specific issue. Sorry if that's not it.  If you don't mind a bit of light hacking, grab a SQLite program (there is a good one for firefox for example), and check the fields associated with the image, there's a metadata digest (think checksum) and a develop digest (which relates to specific develop settings).  If you can tell which is changing, seemingly incorrectly, it may be a start.  Telling the circumstances that change them may require experimentation.

Comment: One impression I've developed (and it's only that; I haven't tested it extensively) is that if the image is already in a Published Service, simply adding it to another Published Service sometimes seems to be enough for it to be marked for re-publishing in the original Published Service.